# A better way to write a void closure with [weak self]?

Tags: swift

I wonder if there's a better way to get rid of a nasty compiler when using [weak self] in a void closure. Here's an example:

```
class Foo {
    let callback: ()->()

    init() {
        callback = { [weak self] in self?.bar() }  // PROBLEM!
    }

    func bar() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The compiler reports "cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type '$T7?'". The cause: a closure uses the last sentence as a return value. And since `self`is optional, the `bar()` call result is `Void?`... which does not comply with the closure type `()->()`.

Therefore I must tweak the problematic line like this:

```
callback = { [weak self] in self?.bar(); return }
```

Is there a cleaner way to appease the compiler?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: That *is* a clean way. Note that Swift 1.2/Xcode 6.3 beta does not have this problem anymore.

Comment: @MartinR Ah, good news Martin. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I think there was a similar discussion here before, but it is difficult to find. Another suggested workaround was to assign the value of the statement to an anonymous variable, but I still like the explicit return most.

Comment: @MartinR if you add an answer for that  Swift 1.2/Xcode 6.3 beta information, I'll vote you up.

Answer (score 1):

*(From my above comment:)* 
Adding an explicit `return` statement is a clean solution.
However, it not necessary
anymore with Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3). From the beta release notes:

> Unannotated single-expression closures with non-Void return types can now be used in Void contexts.